# Setting Receive Packet Steering (RPS) for 32 cores

Tags: linux-kernel, multiprocessing

I am not sure that I used the correct commands for setting the RPS for a 32 cores machine. This is what I used: echo 1f > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus

Should it be "echo 1f..." or "echo f..." or anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pinterest engineers just [say](https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/building-pinterest-in-the-cloud-6c7280dcc196):

```
echo f > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
```

But there are another [their talk](http://www.slideshare.net/denshikarasu/all-your-iops-are-belong-to-us-a-pinteresting-case-study-in-mysql-performance-optimization):

```
echo ffff > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
```

Can't see the actual difference from kernel point of view but you can try both

Answer (score 4):

Reproducing from the [**Performance Tuning Guide**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Networking-Configuration_tools.html#sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Configuration_tools-Configuring_Receive_Packet_Steering_RPS) for **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7**:

> The rps_cpus files use comma-delimited CPU bitmaps. Therefore, to
>   allow a CPU to handle interrupts for the receive queue on an
>   interface, set the value of their positions in the bitmap to 1. For
>   example, to handle interrupts with CPUs 0, 1, 2, and 3, set the value
>   of rps_cpus to 00001111 (1+2+4+8), or f (the hexadecimal value for
>   15).

So for quad-core cpus...

```
echo f > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
```

and for cpus with >4 cores...

```
echo ff+ > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
```

where ff+ is a **regex** for appending extra f(s) for each set of additional 4 cores

Comment: Where did you find the documentation that specifies that the `rps_cpus` flag accepts the `ff+` regex?

Comment: Gustavo, that's not what he's saying -- he's expecting the stackoverflow user to accept the regex and provide an appropriate number of effs.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using binary calculator and nproc:

```bash
echo "obase=16;2^$(nproc)-1" | bc > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
```

That formula will configure RPS for any number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen also `<flags>,<flags>,<flags>` notation. My machine refuses to accept that.
Other than this I also see that after reboot the values got reset to 0. I bypass it by defining enabling and starting the service that corrects the value to ff (that is what I wanted it to be).

Answer (score -3):

I used this

```
# Input
NIC_NAME="em1";
if [[ "$1" != "" ]]; then
    NIC_NAME="$1";
fi

# Tuna Install 
#echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Install numactl" ;
#yum install -y tuna ;

# Tuna Config
echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Tuna Info: " ;
tuna --irqs=${NIC_NAME}-\* --cpus=0-3 --move --spread ;
tuna --irqs=${NIC_NAME}-txrx-\* --cpus=0-3 --move --spread ;
tuna --irqs=${NIC_NAME}-tx-\* --cpus=0-3 --move --spread ;
tuna --irqs=${NIC_NAME}-rx-\* --cpus=0-3 --move --spread ;
tuna --irqs=${NIC_NAME}-\* --show_irqs ;

# Install
#echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Install numactl" ;
#yum install -y numactl ;
#echo "";

# Numa Info
echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Numa Info: " ;
numactl --hardware | grep "^node . cpus" ;
echo "";

# Numa Mask
echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Numa Mask: " ;
NUMA_COUNT=$(numactl --hardware | grep "^node . cpus\:" | wc -l);
NUMA_MASK=("");
i=0;
while [ $i -lt ${NUMA_COUNT} ]; do
    NUMA_MASK[$i]=$(numactl --hardware | grep "^node $i cpus\:" | awk -F':' '{ print $2}' | sed 's/ /\+2\^/g' | awk '{print "obase=16;0" $0}' | bc | rev | sed -e 's/\([0-F][0-F][0-F][0-F][0-F][0-F][0-F][0-F]\)/\1,/g' | rev);
    echo " NUMA_MASK[$i]: ${NUMA_MASK[$i]}";
    let i++;
done
echo "";

# Set RPS/XPS
echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Set RPS/XPS: " ;
QUEUE_RX_COUNT=0;
QUEUE_TX_COUNT=0;
i=0;
while [ $i -lt 16 ]; do
    let NUMA_ID=(i % NUMA_COUNT);
    QUEUE_RX_RPS="/sys/class/net/${NIC_NAME}/queues/rx-$i/rps_cpus";
    QUEUE_TX_XPS="/sys/class/net/${NIC_NAME}/queues/tx-$i/xps_cpus";
    if [[ -e "${QUEUE_RX_RPS}" && "${NUMA_MASK[$NUMA_ID]}" != "" ]]; then
        echo ${NUMA_MASK[$NUMA_ID]} > "${QUEUE_RX_RPS}" ;
        NUMA_MASK_ID=$(cat "${QUEUE_RX_RPS}");
        echo " ${QUEUE_RX_RPS}: $NUMA_MASK_ID" ;
        let QUEUE_RX_COUNT++;
    fi;
    if [[ -e "${QUEUE_TX_XPS}" && "${NUMA_MASK[$NUMA_ID]}" != "" ]]; then
        echo ${NUMA_MASK[$NUMA_ID]} > "${QUEUE_TX_XPS}" ;
        NUMA_MASK_ID=$(cat "${QUEUE_TX_XPS}");
        echo " ${QUEUE_TX_XPS}: $NUMA_MASK_ID" ;
        let QUEUE_TX_COUNT++;
    fi;
    let i++;
done
echo "";

# Set Sock Rps Flow
echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Set Sock Rps Flow: " ;
SOCK_RX_FLOW_ENTRIES="/proc/sys/net/core/rps_sock_flow_entries" ;
SOCK_RX_FLOW_COUNT=32768 ;
echo "${SOCK_RX_FLOW_COUNT}" > ${SOCK_RX_FLOW_ENTRIES} ;
SOCK_RX_FLOW_COUNT=$(cat ${SOCK_RX_FLOW_ENTRIES}) ;
echo " ${SOCK_RX_FLOW_ENTRIES}: ${SOCK_RX_FLOW_COUNT}" ;
echo "";

# Set Queue Rps Flow
echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` - Set Queue Rps Flow: " ;
let SET_QUEUE_RX_FLOW_COUNT=(SOCK_RX_FLOW_COUNT / QUEUE_RX_COUNT);
i=0;
while [ $i -lt 16 ]; do
    QUEUE_RX_FLOW="/sys/class/net/${NIC_NAME}/queues/rx-$i/rps_flow_cnt";
    if [[ -e "${QUEUE_RX_FLOW}" && ${SET_QUEUE_RX_FLOW_COUNT} -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo ${SET_QUEUE_RX_FLOW_COUNT} > "${QUEUE_RX_FLOW}" ;
        GET_QUEUE_RX_FLOW_COUNT=$(cat "${QUEUE_RX_FLOW}");
        echo " ${QUEUE_RX_FLOW}: ${GET_QUEUE_RX_FLOW_COUNT}" ;
    fi;
    let i++;
done
echo "";
```

Comment: You must state the problem if you desire help.